# Python 2.7.9 Mac OS 10.10.3 Message "setCanCycle: is deprecated. Please use setCollectionBehavior instead"

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, anaconda, spyder

This is my first message and i hope can you help me to solve my problem.

When I launch a python script I have this message :

> 2015-06-10 23:15:44.146 python[1044:19431] setCanCycle: is deprecated.Please use setCollectionBehavior instead
>
> 2015-06-10 23:15:44.155 python[1044:19431] setCanCycle: is deprecated.Please use setCollectionBehavior instead

Below my script :

```
from Tkinter import *
 
root = Tk()
 
root.geometry("450x600+10+10")
root.title("Booleanv1.0")
 
Cadre_1 = Frame(root, width=400, height=100)
Cadre_1.pack(side='top')
 
fileA = Label(Cadre_1, text="File A")
fileA.grid(row=0,column=0)
entA = Entry(Cadre_1, width=40)
entA.grid(row=0,column=1, pady=10)
open_fileA = Button(Cadre_1, text='SELECT', width=10, height=1, command = root.destroy)
open_fileA.grid(row=0, column=2)
 
fileB = Label(Cadre_1, text="File B")
fileB.grid(row=1,column=0)
entB = Entry(Cadre_1, width=40)
entB.grid(row=1,column=1, pady=10)
open_fileB = Button(Cadre_1, text='SELECT', width=10, height=1, command = root.destroy)
open_fileB.grid(row=1, column=2)
 
 
root.mainloop()
```

Who can help me to explain this message ?

how can I do to remove this message ?

PS : I use Anaconda 3.10.0 and Spyder IDE, but I have the same problem when I launch my script with the terminal.

regards.

Answer (score 9):

The version of the Tkinter library which Anaconda has installed was compiled on an older version of OS X. The warnings your seeing aren't actually a problem and will go away once a version of the library compiled on a more recent version of OS X are added to the Anaconda repository.
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/y1UWpFHsDyQ